# How to Compile java7 code with IKVMC for .NET framework 3.5 support?

Tags: .net, sql-server, clr, java-7, ikvm

I am trying to produce a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express R2 Stored Procedure (C#) CLR from some code that is compiled that references a dll cross compiled using IKVMC. The original code is written in java7. Problem is IKVM is giving me a .NET framework 4.0 assembly. SQL Server 2008 does not support .NET framework 4.0! I am wondering if there is a way to get my assembly to be cross compiled to .NET framework 3.5 instead of 4.0?

Lists the supported platforms for IKVM including '.NET 2.0 SP2  x64 Windows' which I would like to target:
http://weblog.ikvm.net/PermaLink.aspx?guid=692505a6-f9e7-45ec-90b9-ec7a75d3b509

Have been looking at the IKVMC options here:
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=Ikvmc

It is not clear to me how to specify '.NET 2.0 SP2' or framework 3.5?

Further, I am stuck with SQL Server 2008 so I can't simply just upgrade to a new version to get framework 4.0 support.

Comment: I was able to get the IKVM.Runtime.dll loaded into SQL Server 2008 by loading dependencies System.Windows.Forms.dll and System.Drawing.dll from 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727' I guess these dlls are backwards compatible to v1.1 according to: http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/intro.html ... hoping my built dll will now load too.

Comment: It feels a little strange to have to manually load these assemblies into SQL Server 2008? Shouldn't they be available by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IKVM is compiled for .net 2.0. This means it works without problems for .NET 2.0 to 3.5. If you use .NET 4.0 then you need to tricky with the app.config file.

If all needed dlls are in the same directory you should not have any problems with static loading of the dlls.

There can be a problem with compiling your dll. See [classloader wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=ClassLoader) for details.

The error message that you receive can be helpful if this not help. The best help for IKVM you receive with the mailing list.

Comment: Yea, got it working yesterday. The root of my confusion was over the manually dll loading of the System.Drawing and System.Windows.Forms dlls. I wasn't understanding if the dll was compatible why it would be looking for these? Shouldn't they be loaded automatically? Guess not. Thanks for your feedback. Will give you the check!